# Office: personal licence with Campus storage

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I have a standalone Office 365 subscription (uni student version, I paid for this), but I'd like to use it with the campus-wide-shared OneDrive (it's a completely different account and domain on sharepoint.com).

If I understand correctly, there's no OneDrive for Business client for Windows 10. I'm a heavy user of my personal OneDrive account on W10Pro.

I've added my campus-account under settings / work account, but it still didn't show up under my OneDrive folder / Network or anywhere.

Should I uninstall my paid version, and use the campus version to connect to this other storage account? Will it override my personal onedrive?